# Forcing ffmpeg to generate segments with constant duration

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to generate HLS version 3 manifest with segments .ts files that have the same duration.

My input to ffmpeg either ADTS AAC or mp4 file. In ffmpeg command line I specified segment duration that is whole number of AAC frames. However ffmpeg still does not produce segments that vary from one to another.

Comment: Share full command and console log.

Comment: Full console log missing

Comment: ./ffmpeg.exe -i ../test.mp4 -codec copy -hls_time 9.752380952380952 -hls_segment_filename '../out/file%03d.ts' -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_playlist_type vod "../test.m3u8" 



I have 22050 Hz Low Complexity (LC) Mono mp4 audio. I specify segment duration that contains exactly 210 codec frames 

    (210 * 1024 * 1000 / 22050) = 9.752380952380952 s

Comment: The output contains long for writing segments:

[hls @ 00000205f17fe000] Opening '../test.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 00000205f17fe000] Opening '../out/file000.ts' for writing

...

[hls @ 00000205f17fe000] Opening '../test.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 00000205f17fe000] Opening '../out/file977.ts' for writing

Comment: That's fine. Host it at pastebin..etc